# In Kubernetes Python pod, how to notify by email only one time everytime new file arrive in PVC?

Tags: python, kubernetes

In Kubernetes I am trying to monitor and notify by email new files arriving in Persistent Volume Claim. So I tried this in Python :

```
import os
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Email configuration
smtp_server = 'V'
smtp_port = 25
sender_email = 'X'
receiver_email = 'Y'


# Set up the directory to monitor
dir_to_monitor = '/mnt/'

# Set up a list to store processed files
processed_files = []

# Function to recursively explore directories and detect new files
def explore_directory(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            if file_path not in processed_files:
                # New file detected
                processed_files.append(file_path)
                print("New file:", file_path)
                send_notification_email(file_path)

# Function to send email notification
def send_notification_email(file_path):
    subject = 'New file arrived'
    message = f"A new file has arrived:\n\nDirectory: {os.path.dirname(file_path)}\nFile: {file_path}"

    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email

    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
        server.starttls()
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())

# Continuously monitor the directory for new files
while True:
    explore_directory(dir_to_monitor)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Problem is that I receive same email concerning same new file.
Also if my pod is KO and deployed again, processed_files list will be empty again and all files will be considered as new ones.

What can I modify in Kubernetes to have only one mail when a new file arrive in PVC ?

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: (The kinds of persistent volumes that are easy to get can't be mounted into multiple pods, so a shared filesystem might not be the best communication mechanism here.  Can you use a message queue like RabbitMQ or an HTTP message to trigger this instead?)

Comment: @DavidMaze what are the benefits of using RabbitMQ (or Kafka ?) ?